# SQL results doesn't show Korean character field of a mariaDB table

Tags: eclipse, select, encoding, utf-8, mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.1.34 with Eclipse Oxygen. 
I made a simple table, input some records, with a Korean character.
When I execute "select * from member" in the mariaDB console, I can see
the Korean character well, as in the picture. 
But when I execute the same query in the scrapbook of eclipse, 
the result doesn't show the records. I can only see empty line.

I just started learning programming in school so I don't know what is exactly
the problem.

It seems the DB saved the record correctly, but when JDBC is getting data from
the DB, it can't read Korean character. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide  `SHOW CREATE TABLE member\G`  `SELECT name, HEX(name) FROM member;`  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`  They may give clues.